# Error botón modificar combobox

Tags: java, java-swing

[image: Error]

```
public void Modificar(){

        linked.set(tblUsuarios.getSelectedRow(), new clsUsuarios(txtNombre.getText(), txtID.getText(), txtTelefono.getText(), Password.getPassword(),(String) boxTipo.setSelectedItem()));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se Modificó con Éxito ");
        listar();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple vista me parece que tu problema es el último parámetro para instanciar la clase `clsUsuarios`.

```
new clsUsuarios(txtNombre.getText(), txtID.getText(), txtTelefono.getText(), Password.getPassword(),(String) boxTipo.setSelectedItem()));
```

El último parametro usaría el método `getSelectedItem()` no `setSelectedItem()`:

```
(String) boxTipo.getSelectedItem()));
```

o

```
String.valueOf(boxTipo.getSelectedItem()));
```

Debes revisar los valores que necesitas para instanciar la clase, ya que el error :

> incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to String

indica incompatibilidad en el tipo de los datos.

Comment: Listo ya solucioné el error, me fue muy útil tu respuesta, gracias.